# How to validate empty textbox and minimum length in ember.js

Tags: javascript, validation, ember.js

this is my code for name validation using ember validation mixin

```
   App.Data= Ember.Object.extend(Ember.Validations.Mixin, {
        validations: {
            name: {

               length: {
                    minimum: 5,
                    maximum: 15,
                    message: "name is too short"
                },
               presence: true,
                presence: {
                    message: "name can't be blank"
                }
    });
```

this is fine.but it is validating both at once . if textbox is empty it is showing message that name is too short name can't be blank .if length is minimum 5 i am getting the same error message. so i want to get one separate message if it is empty and another message if length is minimum.How to validate empty and length as separate one .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://github.com/dockyard/ember-validations), you can use `allowBlank` length validation option:

> If true skips validation if value is empty

Your validation should look like this:

```
...
length: {
    minimum: 5,
    maximum: 15,
    allowBlank: true,
    message: "name is too short"
},
presence: true,
presence: {
    message: "name can't be blank"
}
...
```

Now it should skip length validation if it's blank.